# Oracle SQL Left Join with multiple tables in FROM

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I am no expert in SQL, but I am faced with SQL query that I need to redesign a bit. I have this:

```
SELECT T1.COULMN1
       T1.COULMN2, 
       T1.COULMN3, 
       T2.COULMN4 
FROM TABLE1 T1, 
     TEST1, 
     TEST2,
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COULMN1 = T2.COULMN1 AND T1.COULMN2 = T2.COULMN2 AND T1.COULMN3 = T2.COULMN3  FROM  
WHERE TEST1.NAME = 'test'
AND TEST2.ADDRESS = 'random'
```

and it won't work as I get "T1.COULMN3 invalid identifier". But if I remove TEST1 and TEST2 from FROM and consequently from WHERE it works. But I need to have TEST1 and TEST2 in FROM and WHERE, how I can achive that?

Comment: What is the key to join TEST1, TEST2 and TABLE1? You just need to join them the way you did for TABLE2. Post the table DDL and sample data to get more help. We cannot debug or fix the code that we can't see.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your question makes no sense and you have no explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multiple LEFT JOINS like below and also need to connect TEST1 and TEST2 to Either TABLE1 or TABLE2 otherwise there is no point in using TEST1 and TEST2.Also provide additional details regarding the relationship between TABLE1, TABLE2 and Test1, Test2.

Note:-Please replace the data between greater than and lesser than with actual relationship between TABLE1, TABLE2 and Test1, Test2.

```
        SELECT T1.coulmn1 t1.COULMN2,
           T1.coulmn3,
           T2.coulmn4
    FROM   table1 T1
           left join table2 T2
                  ON T1.coulmn1 = T2.coulmn1
                     AND T1.coulmn2 = T2.coulmn2
                     AND T1.coulmn3 = T2.coulmn3
           left join test1 T3
                  ON <T3.id> = <T1.id>
                     AND T3.name = 'test'
           left join test2 T4
                  ON <T4.id> = <T2.id>
                     AND T4.address = 'random';
```

Comment: What is the purpose of asking the OP for more details and clarity if answers are made of self assumptions?

Comment: i understand your point, i did it for the correctness of the query

Comment: Appreciate your help to OP, I am just saying that we need to encourage new users to follow community guidelines and post questions with sufficient details.

Comment: got it, i have edited the answer asking the OP for additional details